# Umbraco Related Links missing after V8 upgrade

Tags: .net, umbraco

I have a problem, after upgrade from Umbraco V7 to V8 my related links are missing. I saw that when im getting the information they are still there in the response, but i can't see them in the dashboard. Before the update the Data Type was "RelatedLinks" and after update the Data Type is "Multi Url Picker"

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqCUt.png)

[problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfYN5.png)

[picture with created new related link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9bJ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Related Links data type changed to Multi Url Picker](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-8/96405-related-links-umbraco-8#comment-304799) on Umbraco v8. Your first step should be to check whether your problem is a configuration or data issue.

To check whether this is a data issue, you can create a new page, using the same document type (and data types). If it is not showing any error, then it must be related to data.

If it is a data error, then you can try looking for solutions to update or create the data.

If you don't have many pages that have this problem, you might want to consider manually creating/updating the content pages that have this problem. Another option is to check the database to find out the missing bits and update the data via some scripts.

Final approach could be to try fixing the data problem by creating a ValueConverter, similar to this one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.PublishedCache;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Web;

namespace AnUmbracoV10ProjectName.Configurator.Core.Util
{
    public class IntUdiMultiNodeTreePickerValueConverter : MultiNodeTreePickerValueConverter
    {
        private readonly IPublishedSnapshotAccessor _publishedSnapshotAccessor;

        public IntUdiMultiNodeTreePickerValueConverter(IPublishedSnapshotAccessor publishedSnapshotAccessor, IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor, IMemberService memberService) : base(publishedSnapshotAccessor, umbracoContextAccessor, memberService)
        {
            _publishedSnapshotAccessor = publishedSnapshotAccessor;
        }

        public override object? ConvertSourceToIntermediate(IPublishedElement owner, IPublishedPropertyType propertyType, object? source, bool preview)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (propertyType.EditorAlias.Equals(Umbraco.Cms.Core.Constants.PropertyEditors.Aliases.MultiNodeTreePicker))
            {
                Udi?[]? nodeIds = source.ToString()?
                    .Split(Umbraco.Cms.Core.Constants.CharArrays.Comma, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(ParseUdiOrInt)
                    .ToArray();
                return nodeIds;
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected Udi? ParseUdiOrInt(string id)
        {
            if (UdiParser.TryParse(id, out var udi))
            {
                return udi;
            }

            if (Int32.TryParse(id, out var integer))
            {
                if (_publishedSnapshotAccessor.TryGetPublishedSnapshot(out var publishedSnapshot))
                {
                    var item = publishedSnapshot?.Media?.GetById(integer);

                    if (item is not null)
                    {
                        return new GuidUdi(Umbraco.Cms.Core.Constants.UdiEntityType.Media, item.Key);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, i see that when the backoffice app hits the endpoint "GetById" im getting information about the links. Please check again the original question i attached an image showing the returned result from the api. Want to mention that im still with the absolutely empty 8.5 project without any controllers or pages. I should move all the pieces when i reach the last version of Umbraco with working database.

Comment: An empty 8.5 project without any controllers or pages is the correct approach. Once you resolve your major data migration issues, you can focus on working on your controllers, templates etc. 

GetById is an Umbraco service call to get the content. It is normal to see that. Seems like you have "buttonComponent" nested content data type. I'd check this data type to make sure the setup is correct. Check your v7 project as a reference. After making sure the setup is correct, and if you still see some problems, take a look at the code example that I have shared.

Comment: Btw these data migration issues are mostly Umbraco migration errors. ProWorks.Umbraco8.Migrations resolves many of the migration issues: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProWorks.Umbraco8.Migrations 

See Step 5 on my blog post for additional details about this package. https://skrift.io/issues/how-i-upgraded-my-umbraco-v7-project-to-umbraco-v11/

Comment: I tried the way what u mention with the ProWorks, but im at the stage where, the Nested components are missing when i switch the language, and the links are still missing. Let me explain my steps. Upgdate from 7.14.7 to 8.18.9(latest V8). Installed fresh V8 project, pointed to the database from my V7 project, installed Proworks migration package and just started the upgrade process normally. Please tell me if u need more details.

Comment: I have to migrate up to the V12, there are no Nested content, can i change my nested content to something else before any migrations? That way maybe the migration should be more proper and after that i should not carry about Nested Content again when i reach V12?

Comment: Here are the steps that I follow to upgrade my v7 projects to v12: https://skrift.io/issues/how-i-upgraded-my-umbraco-v7-project-to-umbraco-v11/

Comment: In terms of resolving Nested Content-related issues before upgrading your project to v12 - this is a business decision that you should discuss with your company and client.  Nested content won't be available on v13 but there is also a new Umbraco back office coming on v14, this will be another big migration, this time from v12/v13 to v14 (there is still time for this big (future) upgrade): https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-backoffice/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-new-backoffice

Comment: Also, remember my first recommendation: "Your first step should be to check whether your problem is a configuration or data issue." I have seen similar problems before and they were mostly data type (nested content mostly)setup issues. Value converters also helped me resolve some problems. 

PS: If you have a new question, remember to ask a new one rather than updating your original question. This is how StackOverflow works. Also, remember to upvote/accept useful/correct answers.

Comment: Im feeling really close to the successful database upgrade from V7 to V8, only the Nested Content is broken(only nested components didnt come in the dashboard when i switch to the second language variant) and the links into these Button components what are Nested in my case. I should fire up new upgrade from V7 to V8 to see if something should change and should comment when have any updates.

Comment: A new upgrade shouldn't change any of your results assuming you are following my 12 steps. Just check your Nested content setup. I am not sure how language variant affects this problem btw. You can potentially do some research on Umbraco forum or ask a question on Umbraco Discord channel.

Comment: Yep the new upgrade didnt change anything. Still stuck on the problem with nested content, its really strange if i change the nested property in my document types to be "Allow vary by culture" all the "Page Components" disappear. If the "Allow vary by culture" is disabled i can see the "Page Components" but they are disabled and can't be touched...

Comment: Good luck with your variant fixes. Make sure to upvote useful answers and mark the correct answers. Also if you have new questions, please ask a new one so that more people can help you. 

Please take a look at the StackOverflow guide for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask